# Merging Two Geographic Files

Tags: r, merge, geospatial, data-manipulation, lookup

I am using R, I have the two following "geographic files" (i.e. shapefiles):

- Bigger Units : https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/82-402-x/2018001/data-donnees/boundary-limites/arcinfo/HR_000a18a-eng.zip
- Smaller Units: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lfsa000b16a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2044221&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lfsa000b16a_e.zip

Once I download these folders, I import them them into R as follows:

```
Bigger_Units  <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/ME/OneDrive/Documents/hr_shape/HR_000a18a_e.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252") %>%  sf::st_transform('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')

Smaller_Units <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/ME/OneDrive/Documents/shape7/lfsa000b16a_e.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252") %>%  sf::st_transform('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
```

Once imported, they look something like this:

```
> head(Smaller_Units)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -60.67924 ymin: 45.72791 xmax: -59.93641 ymax: 46.26758
CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
  CFSAUID PRUID                        PRNAME                       geometry
1     B1E    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.00359 4...
2     B1G    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.00298 4...
3     B1H    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.04267 4...
4     B1J    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.2913 46...
5     B1K    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-59.99001 4...
6     B1L    12 Nova Scotia / Nouvelle-Écosse MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.1559 46...

> head(Bigger_Units)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 5 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -82.80346 ymin: 42.05986 xmax: -76.16181 ymax: 45.43812
CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
  HR_UID                                                  ENGNAME                                                                 FRENAME
1   3537                             City of Hamilton Health Unit                       Circonscription sanitaire de la citÃ© de Hamilton
2   3538          Hastings and Prince Edward Counties Health Unit      Circonscription sanitaire des comtÃ©s de Hastings et Prince Edward
3   3539                                 Huron County Health Unit                            Circonscription sanitaire du comtÃ© de Huron
4   3540                                 Chatham-Kent Health Unit                               Circonscription sanitaire de Chatham-Kent
5   3541 Kingston, Frontenac and Lennox and Addington Health Unit Circonscription sanitaire de Kingston, Frontenac et Lennox et Addington
6   3542                                      Lambton Health Unit                                    Circonscription sanitaire de Lambton
  SHAPE_AREA SHAPE_LEN                       geometry
1 1212618763  173963.7 MULTIPOLYGON (((-79.86045 4...
2 9131935097  569876.5 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.69017 4...
3 3696168189  335661.7 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.97369 4...
4 3078455510  269377.6 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.8351 42...
5 8174790022  460742.3 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.79163 4...
6 4172673622  398518.1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.76871 4...
```

**I have a feeling that units within the "smaller_units" file can be combined together to create units within the "bigger_units" file.** For example:

```
> head(Bigger_Units$ENGNAME)
[1] "City of Hamilton Health Unit"                             "Hastings and Prince Edward Counties Health Unit"         
[3] "Huron County Health Unit"                                 "Chatham-Kent Health Unit"                                
[5] "Kingston, Frontenac and Lennox and Addington Health Unit" "Lambton Health Unit" 

> head(Smaller_Units$CFSAUID)
[1] "B1E" "B1G" "B1H" "B1J" "B1K" "B1L"
```

**As a hypothetical example, perhaps if you considered the total area covered by "B1E, B1G and B1H" - they would be equal to "City of Hamilton Health Unit".**  That is, the geographical area of the smaller units (as specified by the range of longitudes and latitudes within the "geometry" column in the shapefile) might perfectly coincide with the geographical area of a bigger unit. This might be possible through some form of lookup/match.

**In the end, I would like to try and get the following output:**

```
#desired output

 smaller_units    corresponding_bigger_unit
1           B1E City of Hamilton Health Unit
2           B1G City of Hamilton Health Unit
3           B1H City of Hamilton Health Unit
4           B1J     Huron County Health Unit
5           B1K     Huron County Health Unit
6           B1L     Huron County Health Unit
```

But I am not sure how to perform lookup/matches using geographical files with longitude/latitude ranges.

Can someone please suggest how this might be done?

Thank you!

PS: Suppose a given "Smaller Unit" appears in more than one "Bigger Unit" - how will the merge be able to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried `sf::st_join()` which gives various options to join two sf file based on spatial relationship.

Comment: @  Niranjan Poudel : Thank you so much for suggesting this! I will start researching this function! If you have time, could you please show me an example? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of using the st_join() function.

Use `?st_join` to check the options to join the features based on. Here in this example I have used `st_contains`.
You can change `left = FALSE` to keep all the rows even if they do not satisfy the join conditions.

```
library(sf)

sf_use_s2(FALSE)

Bigger_Units <- st_read("HR_000a18a-eng/HR_000a18a_e/HR_000a18a_e.shp", 
                        options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252" ) %>%
  st_transform(crs = 4326)

Smaller_Units <- st_read("lfsa000b16a_e/lfsa000b16a_e.shp", 
                         options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252") %>%
  st_transform(crs = 4326)


## Joined data
Dat <- st_join(Bigger_Units, Smaller_Units, join = st_contains, left = TRUE)
```

Also note the geometry of the x (first sf data.frame) will be preserved in the final data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! When I tried your code I got the following error:

Comment: rror in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) : 
  Evaluation error: Found 3 features with invalid spherical geometry.
[21] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 6509 has duplicate vertex with edge 6521
[27] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 49 has duplicate vertex with edge 5931
[49] Loop 9 is not valid: Edge 1402 has duplicate vertex with edge 1574.

Comment: Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: It might be something to do with spherical geometry and planer geometry. One way to avoid the error is use  `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`  code before using sf functions  and switching to planer geometry, but I am not sure about how it impacts the accuracy and everything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If you have time, could you please show me an example of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have edited and added the code above. Just add that line to turn off spherical geometry I guess

Comment: I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: The `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` works for me for the same data. But you can also try `... %>% st_transform(crs= 4326) %>% st_make_valid()`  for one or both file.  Read about it https://r-spatial.org/book/04-Spherical.html#validity-on-the-sphere. Also similar issues https://github.com/rsbivand/BMP21_data/issues/1,  https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1762

Comment: Thank you I think this is working better now!